# How can I get only +7927xxxxxxx mobile numbers from contact list?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I have an app that has to show my phone contact list. But how can I get only +7927xxxxxxx mobile numbers?

```
private void createListView(View fragmentView) {
    contactList = (ListView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.list_contacts);
    contactsAdapter = getContactAdapter(contactList);

    contactList.setAdapter(contactsAdapter);        
    contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnContactClickListener());
}
```

Comment: How do You obtain contacts? Are You doing request to ContentProvider?

Comment: what exactly `getContactAdapter` do? this why it takes ListView as parameter? this code makes no sens ... backing to answer ... well you need to qury Contacts ContentProvider with `query` method and provide `"LIKE '+7927%'"` as where parameter ...

Comment: @ANDROID_SDK@\samples\android-8\ContactManager\ContactManager.java in `private Cursor getContacts()` change `selection` to `"LIKE..."` from my prev comment